# appium server failure to launch

Tags: server, appium

As i start appium and i try to run a server this error occurs.Can anybody enlighten the situtaion?the error message is:
"> error: uncaughtException: Cannot find module './modules/core.log' date=Mon Jul 06 2015 16:15:44 GMT+0300 (GTB Daylight Time), pid=5760, uid=null, gid=null, cwd=C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium, execPath=C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node.exe, version=v0.10.26, argv=[C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node.exe, C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\lib\server\main.js, --address, 127.0.0.1, --port, 4723, --platform-name, Android, --platform-version, 18, --automation-name, Appium, --log-no-color], rss=52850688, heapTotal=41425356, heapUsed=22636520, loadavg=[0, 0, 0], uptime=22180.685661, trace=[column=15, file=module.js, function=Function.Module._resolveFilename, line=338, method=Module._resolveFilename, native=false, column=25, file=module.js, function=Function.Module._load, line=280, method=Module._load, native=false, column=17, file=module.js, function=Module.require, line=364, method=require, native=false, column=17, file=module.js, function=require, line=380, method=null, native=false, column=1, file=x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-xcode\node_modules\babel-runtime\node_modules\core-js\library\index.js, function=Object. (C:\Program Files, line=14, method= (C:\Program Files, native=false, column=26, file=module.js, function=Module._compile, line=456, method=_compile, native=false, column=10, file=module.js, function=Object.Module._extensions..js, line=474, method=Module._extensions..js, native=false, column=32, file=module.js, function=Module.load, line=356, method=load, native=false, column=12, file=module.js, function=Function.Module._load, line=312, method=Module._load, native=false, column=17, file=module.js, function=Module.require, line=364, method=require, native=false, column=17, file=module.js, function=require, line=380, method=null, native=false, column=14, file=x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-xcode\node_modules\babel-runtime\core-js.js, function=Object. (C:\Program Files, line=2, method= (C:\Program Files, native=false, column=26, file=module.js, function=Module._compile, line=456, method=_compile, native=false, column=10, file=module.js, function=Object.Module._extensions..js, line=474, method=Module._extensions..js, native=false, column=32, file=module.js, function=Module.load, line=356, method=load, native=false, column=12, file=module.js, function=Function.Module._load, line=312, method=Module._load, native=false, column=17, file=module.js, function=Module.require, line=364, method=require, native=false, column=17, file=module.js, function=require, line=380, method=null, native=false, column=13, file=x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-xcode\build\lib\xcode.js, function=Object. (C:\Program Files, line=5, method= (C:\Program Files, native=false, column=26, file=module.js, function=Module._compile, line=456, method=_compile, native=false, column=10, file=module.js, function=Object.Module._extensions..js, line=474, method=Module._extensions..js, native=false, column=32, file=module.js, function=Module.load, line=356, method=load, native=false, column=12, file=module.js, function=Function.Module._load, line=312, method=Module._load, native=false, column=17, file=module.js, function=Module.require, line=364, method=require, native=false, column=17, file=module.js, function=require, line=380, method=null, native=false, column=13, file=x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-instruments\lib\future.js, function=Object. (C:\Program Files, line=4, method= (C:\Program Files, native=false], stack=[Error: Cannot find module './modules/core.log',     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15),     at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25),     at Module.require (module.js:364:17),     at require (module.js:380:17),     at Object. (C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-xcode\node_modules\babel-runtime\node_modules\core-js\library\index.js:14:1),     at Module._compile (module.js:456:26),     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10),     at Module.load (module.js:356:32),     at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12),     at Module.require (module.js:364:17),     at require (module.js:380:17),     at Object. (C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-xcode\node_modules\babel-runtime\core-js.js:2:14),     at Module._compile (module.js:456:26),     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10),     at Module.load (module.js:356:32),     at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12),     at Module.require (module.js:364:17),     at require (module.js:380:17),     at Object. (C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-xcode\build\lib\xcode.js:5:13),     at Module._compile (module.js:456:26),     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10),     at Module.load (module.js:356:32),     at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12),     at Module.require (module.js:364:17),     at require (module.js:380:17),     at Object. (C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-instruments\lib\future.js:4:13)]"

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
> brew install node      # get node.js
```

Comment: i have already downloaded node.js and installed it,although the problem insists